# Remove Traceback statement in a KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, command-line, error-handling

I have a simple script:

```
i=1
while True:
    try:
        print i
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise Exception("Ended by user.")
    i = i+1
```

and when I interrupt it, it prints out:
[image]

How can I have it just print out the last line "Exception: Ended by user.", and not the "Traceback..." statement.

Comment: just `print("Exception: Ended by user."); sys.exit(1)`

Answer (score 2):

to emulate the exception but without the traceback, you could just print a message and exit with a non-zero code:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Ended by user.")
    sys.exit(1)
```